# Is there anything similar to JavaScript's spread operator for OCaml's records?

Tags: ocaml

I wonder if OCaml can do something similar to the code below (in TypeScript):

```
interface User {
  name: string
  email: string
}

function titi(user: User) {
  console.log(user)
}

let u1 = {name: "v2"}
let u2 = {...u1, email: "v2@x.y.z"}

titi(u2)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not completely clear what you're asking for. But the closest construct in OCaml is probably `with` in a record constructor:

```
type user = { name : string; email : string }

let user_a = { name = "ua"; email = "e" }
let user_b = { user_a with name = "ub" }
```

(Naturally in OCaml you have to construct a full record value, you can't just have one of the fields.)

Answer (score 0):

As an addendum to Jeffrey's answer, if you have a variant type with a constructor that uses a record, things become slightly more interesting, but you can still use this.

Doesn't work:

```
type user = User of { name : string; email : string }

let user_a = User { name="ua"; email="e" }
let user_b = User { user_a with name="ub" }
```

However, if we pattern-match out the record part of the value, we can:

```
let user_a = User { name="ua"; email="e" }
let user_b = 
  match user_a with
  | User r -> User { r with name="ub" }
```

We can pattern-match components of the record and apply this using the `as` keyword:

```
let user_a = User { name="ua"; email="e" }
let user_b = 
  match user_a with
  | User ({name=n; _} as r) -> User { r with name=n^"2" }
```

Of course, when using `match` with a single pattern, we could just use a local binding.

```
let user_a = User { name="ua"; email="e" }
let user_b = 
  let User ({name=n; _} as r) = user_a in
  User { r with name=n^"2" }
```